# angularjs get a object from ng-repeat to a controller in a different page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have tried a lot of ways, services , $rootScope, broadcast...

I just want to get an instance of the object in the ng-repeat that the user choose, and list its attributes into a new html page dynamically.

Can someone show me the best solution for this case? Everything I've tried so far has gone wrong.

I have two controllers one for the page 1 and another one for page 2 and a service that contains my list.

```
app.service('selectedPost', function() {

  var list = { ... };
  var post;

    return {
        getPost: function() {
            return post;
        },
        setPost: function(p) {
            post = p;
        }
});





app.controller('page2Ctrl', function($scope, selectedPost, $rootScope) {
        //tried:
        $scope.obj = selectedPost.getPost();

        //tried
        $scope.obj = {p : selectedPost.getPost() };

        //tried:
        $scope.obj = $rootScope.pobj;
    });

    app.controller('pageCtrl', function($scope, selectedPost, $rootScope) {
        //I call this method in my page1 html and pass the ng-repeat object as parameter:
        //tried:
        $scope.selectPost = function(post) {
            selectedPost.setPost(post);
        };
        //tried:
        $scope.selectPost = function(post) {
            $rootScope.pobj = post;
        };

        $scope.postList = selectedPost.getPostList();

        $scope.totalItems = $scope.postList.length;
        $scope.itemsPerPage = 6;
        $scope.currentPage = 1;
        $scope.maxSize = 5;

        $scope.setPage = function (pageNo) {
           $scope.currentPage = pageNo;
        };

        $scope.pageChanged = function() {
           console.log('Page changed to: ' + $scope.currentPage);
        };

        $scope.pageCount = function () {
            return Math.ceil($scope.postList.length / $scope.itemsPerPage);
        };

        $scope.filter = function(items, groupedBy) {
        if (items) {
           var finalItems = [],
              thisGroup;
           for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            if (!thisGroup) {
                thisGroup = [];
            }
            thisGroup.push(items[i]);
            if (((i+1) % groupedBy) === 0) {
                finalItems.push(thisGroup);
                thisGroup = null;
            }
           }
           if (thisGroup) {
              finalItems.push(thisGroup);
           }
           return finalItems;
        }
      };

       $scope.$watch('currentPage + itemsPerPage', function() {
           var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.itemsPerPage),
           end = begin + $scope.itemsPerPage;

          $scope.filteredItems = $scope.postList.slice(begin, end);
          $scope.listFilter = $scope.filter($scope.filteredItems, 2);
          });
    });
```

page1.html

```
<div ng-controller="pageCtrl">
   <div class="row" ng-repeat="itemList in listFilter">
        <div class="col-md-6" ng-repeat="post in itemList">
           ....
           <input class="button" type="submit" value="More" ng-click="selectPost(post)"/>
           ....//redirect to page2.html
        </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

page2.html file:

```
<div ng-controller="page2Ctrl">{{obj.something}}</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: This seems like it should be working. Have you tried verifying if selectPrpp is called ? With what argument ? What does getPost return ?

Comment: selectPost is called, but getPost() return undefined, so this code is right?

Comment: Where are you trying to get `listFilter` from? it isn't defined in the controller and isn't being returned by the service (and thus is unusable)

Comment: @VitorFreitas: The core logic seems to **[work as expected](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/e1x69wmx/)**. It must be something else that is breaking it. You still didn't answer 1 of my 3 questions. Feel free to edit the fiddle and make a reproduction of your problem.

Comment: @ExpertSystem Sample of my problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/sSBnE7gllFc0F6197cUD?p=info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are loading a totally different page (full-page reload) and instantiating a whole new Angular app.
You can't pass state across apps and reloads using a service, because the service will be instantiated anew with each app/reload.

I suspect that you are trying to implement routing in a SPA (and not traditional full-page loads).
In which case you should use a routing module, like `ngRoute` or `ui.router`.

E.g.:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    ...
    <ng-view></ng-view>
    ...
    <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular-route.js"></script>
</body>

angular.
    module('myApp', ['ngRoute']).
    config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
        when('/path1', {
            templateUrl: '...',
            controller:  '...'
        }).
        when('/path2', {...}).
        ...
    }).
    service('selectedPost', ...).
    controller('...', ...).
    ...
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/e1x69wmx/)**.